# Double pejorative

Tags: word-formation, affixes

Can one say, for example, "la najbarido fuŝkantaĉis la tutan vesperon" or "Dio, iu pagas por lia fuŝbildaĉoj" to show their unbelievable, overwhelming annoyance?

Also, is fuŝ- an obscene prefix?

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange! What meaning would you try to express that way, in contrast to using only _fi-_ or only _-aĉ-_? Consider [edit]ing your question to also include that information, as that might lead to answers more informed and more useful.

Comment: Just to add a data point about this question, there is a [song](https://www.brazilakolekto.com/2018/02/l-anaso.html) which uses exactly this word. I can’t find any uses of fuŝ+aĉ/i in the [Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com/?s=61519016775b5). However it seems fine to me, just probably not a very common usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fuŝ` prefikse multe pli proksimas al `mis` ol al `aĉ`. La ĉefa ideo estas: miso, malĝusteco, maltrafo, malbonfaro kaj volaj kaj nevolaj.

`kantaĉi` jam montras ke la kantado estas malbonkvalita, se oni aldonas `fuŝ` antaŭe oni komprenas:

```
fuŝ-(kant-aĉ-i)
```

Tio povus eĉ signifi kanti bone celante kanti malbone!

Ĉu aŭskultanto povus tamen kompreni la jenon?

```
(fuŝ-kant)-aĉ-i
```

Ni diru ke jes (kvankam `fuŝ` priskribas la tutan postan agon, aĵon), kiu estus do la signifo, ĉu malbone kanti erare?

Pli da informo pri `fuŝ` troveblas [ĉi tie](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/afiksoj/afiksecaj_elementoj/radikoj_kunmetajhoj.html#i-6gs).

Do, por montri ke la kantado estis vere malbona (pli ol `fuŝ-` kaj `-aĉ` malbona), oni povas uzi aliajn elementojn, ekzemple adverbojn. Kaj elekti inter `fuŝ` kaj `aĉ`.

En parolata lingvo oni povas elturniĝi per aliaj elementoj, ekzemple:

```
la najbarido kantaĉadis la tutan vesperon!
la najbarido fuŝkantadis la tutan vesperon!
```

Ĝuste pro tio ke `-ad-` ne vere bezonatas (ja temas pri la tuta vespero) ĝi helpas emfazi la ĉagrenon. Oni povus voĉe substreki `la tutan` aŭ uzi ĝin pli frue en la frazo.

Oni povas aldoni interjekciecajn elementojn antaŭe kiel `ve!`, `nekredeble`, `fuŝ!`, `fek!` en la unua frazo (kie temas ĉefe pri ĉagreno).

En la dua frazo (kie temas ĉefe pri nekredemo) oni povas uzi `nekredeble ke` antaŭe, kaj elekti inter `fuŝpentraĵo` kaj `pentraĵaĉo`:

```
nekredeble, oni pagas ...
```

aŭ igi la frazon (duon)retorika demando:

```
Ĉu (vere) oni pagas por liaj fuŝpentraĵoj?
Ĉu (vere) oni pagas por liaj pentraĵaĉoj?
```

Comment: Nun mi sentas, ke mi estas kompleta komencantino. Dankon!

Answer (score 2):

First, `fuŝ-` is a (verbal) radix, stem word. The usage above is perfectly fine, where English would use two separate words.

- kantaĉi = sing ugly (la rano/knabineto kantaĉis = the frog/little girl sang dreadful)
- fuŝkanti = sing with wrong technique/mastery (like drunk)
- fuŝkantaĉi = both

Here it is a difference in nuance.

Your aim would be something like:

- malbelkantaĉi = ***

Which is an ugly word creation itself.

To strengthen `aĉ` one may use:

- kantaĉegi = sing very dreadfully
- tre aĉe kanti

By the way `kantaĉi` one would not translate natively with `sing`+adverb,
but more something like `whine`, `belt out`, `yodel` (?). But I am not native.

Comment: `fuŝ!` povas ankaŭ funkcii kiel interjekcio, (pli milda ol `fek!`), tion mi aŭdis dirita de junaj denaskuloj.